# How do you parry with the Mech Shield?

Tags: galak-z-the-dimensional

I've done this a couple of times by accident, but can't replicated it regularly.  It seems that you can use the mech form's shield to reflect enemy attacks, both physical and ranged.  However, either there wasn't a tutorial for this feature or I just don't remember how to do it.

How do you parry?

[image: Physical parry]

[image: Ranged parry]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the gifs above and what I read [here](http://www.giantbomb.com/reviews/galak-z-the-dimensional-review/1900-708/):

> You learn how to glide into melee range in broad, beautiful arcs with the mech; you figure out how to actually control the strafe instead of just hoping for the best; you master the timing on the shield, parrying attacks and issuing devastating counters.

It seems a lot like the parry system in Dark Souls, which [this post](http://8bitchimp.com/galak-z-the-dimensional-review/) supports:

> The shield can also be used to parry a la Dark Souls

In terms of how you would pull this off, I'm not entirely sure on what the parry window is for this game, but based on the visual similarity to Dark Souls, I think a safe assumption would be to pull up your shield *right before you are hit by an attack*.